# Influencing the encoding for pages served by meteor?

Tags: meteor

How can I set a encoding for my pages served with meteor? Currently my Firefox keeps on outputting this warning:

`The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must to be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set your encoding inside any `<head>` section of a html file:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Whatever</title>
</head>
```

From Meteor's documentation:

> HTML files in a Meteor application are treated quite a bit differently
>   from a server-side framework. Meteor scans all the HTML files in your
>   directory for three top-level elements: `<head>`, `<body>`, and
>   `<template>`. The head and body sections are separately concatenated
>   into a single head and body, which are transmitted to the client on
>   initial page load.

Comment: D'oh! I somehow convinced myself that I have to manipulate the HTTP headers, but of course the charset can be set in the HTML head section as well.