# Meteor: How to get a custom meta tag on first position in client html

Tags: internet-explorer, meteor

I updated my Meteor based dashboard app from 0.7.x to 0.8.x.

In my customer's environment (app is called from IE within SAP Business One ERP system) I have to send a meta tag

`<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">`

to disable compatibility mode (cm) (cm settings in IE had no effect on IE running within SAP B1). Unfortunately it **must be the first tag within `<head>`** to work. I used the solution from Iwan van Staveren's answer in previous version:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21547378/2336282

But in 0.8.x bundler.js seems to work differently - and I can't figure out how to tweak it again in order to insert the needed tag into client script - or to insert content of my head section at first.

Comment: Found a solution in sending X-UA-Compatible not as meta tag but as an HTTP header as suggested in https://groups.google.com/d/topic/meteor-talk/TUw1v7tX2Yw/discussion.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and solved it by doing:

```
meteor add meteorhacks:inject-initial
```

and creating `server/inject-meta.js` to contain the following:

```
Inject.rawHead('my-meta', 
               '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Dean's** answer helped me with this same exact problem.

I was having issues with my Meteor app constantly flashing in IE. Found out that the *Display intranet sites in Compatibility View* setting was checked.(Tools > Compatibility View Settings) It had to be enabled as that setting is set according to GPO.

Adding the following meta tag forces IE to use the latest version.

Found that adding the meta tag as directed by **Dean** solved this problem.

Thanks!