# Meteor places meta charset tag not on top of head (Windows!)

Tags: javascript, meteor, character-encoding

I am using Meteor on a Windows machine and have the problem, that I cannot use UTF-8 symbols in my templates (öäüÖÄÜ).

### I saw this question on stackoverflow once,

but the solution did not work for me.

This is what I have in my head in the template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

And this is what is being generated and actually is in the head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
**script 1**
**script 2**
...
**script n**
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Why is meteor (or whatever is responsible) pushing all the scripts to the very top? Because of this the charset does not kick in.

### How can I force meta tags to be put right behind the opening HEAD?

The view people dealing with the same problem seem to manipulate something in the meteor boilerplate files, but the paths are always for linux. I can't find those files on my windows machine.

- [Meta tag not in first 1024 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244233/meta-tag-not-in-first-1024-bytes/12246508#12246508)

Can anybody help?
Thanks alot!

Comment: Could you provide a link to the question you're talking about? Even if it did not solve your issue you it could help for understanding your issue.

Comment: of course, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244233/meta-tag-not-in-first-1024-bytes/12246508#12246508