# Unexpected token on 3rd part library

Tags: d3.js, meteor

I'm trying to use a fork of the d3.js library [d3-zoom-pan-extent](https://gist.github.com/mhsmith/5732011)

I have include the file `d3-zoom-pan-extent.js` in `\client\lib` to ensure its available.

The server reports application errors on build
`While building the application:
client/lib/d3-zoom-pan-extent.js:2135:9: Unexpected token ?`

Ordinarily, I would expect this to be a syntax issue, but I verified that `d3-zoom-pan-extent.js` works as expected in an Apache environment.

How can I get this library to run in my Meteor project?

Comment: Does the served html have `<meta charset="utf-8">`? See:  https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1195

Comment: I suspect that apache by default adds the `charset: utf-8` to the `mimetype` of the javascript file which makes it work.

Comment: Thanks @musically_ut, I tried that but to no avail.

Comment: That is surprising. I was fairly sure that this is the problem since the location `2135:9` refers to the symbol `λ` here: `var λ00, φ00, λ0, cosφ0, sinφ0;`.

Comment: in the Apache environment the html file does have `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: I followed [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762371/influencing-the-encoding-for-pages-served-by-meteor) to insert the `<meta>` tag

Comment: Did that solve your problem?

Comment: no, sorry, I think I aticpated you previous comment, so we got out of sync... the problems still exists. If I exclude the offending file from the project, I can confirm that when Meteor runs the app, the `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag is in the `<head>` section

Comment: Thanks you for you assistance... I had introduced the problem myself and the file had been saved with the wrong encoding, which was leading to the error... If you'd like to post the Answer I'll mark it as correct, because it was clearly an encoding issue!

Comment: Although to be clear to anyone reading following this I did write "the server reports" - the `<meta charset="utf-8">` encoding would have been pertient if the client had reporting this... but it is easy to see this after the fact!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fork of `d3`, just like `d3` itself, should be served with the `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag in the `head` or with the content-type header `application/javascript;charset=utf-8`.

Edit:
In this case, the Meteor compiler couldn't build the script for delivery as the source file was wrongly encoded as ANSI. This produced the server error because the `λ` was stored as `?` and thus the server was encountering the `Unexpected token ?`

Comment: it's also essential to ensure the source file is properly encoded as UTF-8 too. In my case, the file had been marked as ANSI. Thanks to @musically_ut I was able to understand what the problem was.